# oracle 10g select with group by throwing exception with same number of columns

Tags: oracle

```
 select 
        case when exists (select "CreatedOn" dategn from "RentedVehicle" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3) 
        then 
        case when exists (select "CreatedOn" dategn from "Transfer" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3) 
        then 
           (select 
           case when rent.dategn>tran.dategn then rent.dategn else tran.dategn end dategn,
           case when rent.dategn>tran.dategn then rent.fuel else tran.fuel end fuel
           from 
              (
               select max("CreatedOn") dategn,"CheckInFuel" fuel 
               from "RentedVehicle" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3 
               group by "RentedVehicle"."CheckInFuel"
              ) rent ,
        (select max("CreatedOn") dategn,"fkFuelLevelId" fuel 
        from "Transfer" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3 group by "Transfer"."fkFuelLevelId") tran) 
        else 
        (select
         max("CreatedOn") dategn,"CheckInFuel" fuel 
        from "RentedVehicle" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3 group by "RentedVehicle"."CheckInFuel") end 
        else 
        case when exists (select "CreatedOn" dategn from "Transfer" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3) 
        then 
        (select max("CreatedOn") dategn,"fkFuelLevelId" fuel 
        from "Transfer" where "fkTempVehicleId"=3 group by "Transfer"."fkFuelLevelId") 
        else 
        (select "CreatedOn" dategn,"InitialFuel" fuel from "TempVehicle" where "pkTempVehicleId"=3) 
        end end  from dual;
```

it is throwing exception

```
ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 2
```

i am sure i am missing something but i tried almost everything. 
please help and elaborate what i missed

Answer (score 2):

Your inline select (part of the `case` statement) returns two values (`dategn` and `fuel`), where only one is allowed:

```
...
then 
(select 
case when rent.dategn>tran.dategn then rent.dategn else tran.dategn end dategn,
case when rent.dategn>tran.dategn then rent.fuel else tran.fuel end fuel
from ...
```

A `case` can only return a single value per row (as it is called per row).

Comment: i removed this line
,
case when rent.dategn>tran.dategn then rent.fuel else tran.fuel end fuel. Same Error

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli - your final select, `(select "CreatedOn" dategn,"InitialFuel" fuel from "TempVehicle" where "pkTempVehicleId"=3)`, has two values too. And the one before that. It's useful to check the line numbers in the errors you get. Maybe you need a new approach to your problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are trying to select from three tables (TempVehicle, Transfer, RentedVehicle) without ever joining them.

Comment: there are two tables having foreign key "fkTempVehicleId", now i have to pick the latest records (if any) present in any of the tables by providing them the foreign key. and if both tables have no records of that id then i have to pick the records from its own table.

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli: then it sends as if you may be better off `UNION`-ing the separate results (so you have consistent column counts, wrapping that in an inline view and selecting the appropriate data sets based on your criteria.